# Use math.h and link objects files without -lm

Tags: linux, gcc

I am currently reading Advanced Linux Programming and in the section 2.3.3
 it is said that if I use some function from math.h I have to link the object files with -lm. But I am pretty sure that I already used some math function like sqrt, pow or log without having to specify the use of this shared library.

Do you see where the problem is?

Thank you

Comment: Are you linking other libraries? If so, they might pull in the math library.

Comment: The rest of the standard library, especialy stdio.h.

Comment: What linker flags are you using?

Comment: None at all, but Mat answered me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always use `-lm` when using functions from `math.h` if you want to keep your code/makefiles portable.

Some of the things in that header are macros (which obviously don't need additional libraries), but which are is not specified (except for a few ones). Some other functions might be implemented as build-ins by your compiler (even replaced by processor-specific opcodes directly), inlined, etc... so the correct linking of your code could also depend on optimizer settings and the exact compiler/version you're using.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double d = 0.2;
    fprintf(stdout, "%f\n", sqrt(d));
    return 0;
}
```

With GCC 4.5.1 on Linux:

```
$ gcc -o t t.c
/tmp/cczCfJsj.o: In function `main':
t.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

$ gcc -O3 -o t t.c
# ok, compiled and linked fine
```

So to save yourself a headache, just add `-lm`.

Comment: Ok, it is like achieve to compile without including a necessary file and discover after and update of gcc that the project does not compile any more. Thx

Comment: I have gcc version 10.5.0 and now I can compile ans use math.h without -lm. Earlier it was not possible if I remember correctly